# Mini/Batch Gradient Descent, sum of gradients

Tags: optimization, algorithms, gradient-descent

Summing all gradients in one mini/batch descent is a special methode or an obligation to get the correct gradient.

Does making median/mean/maxes/... methodes to have different 'global' gradient from sum is usefull ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradients are summed because the loss functions are typically defined as the sum of the individual losses of training samples, and the differentiator distributes over the sum:
$$L=\sum_{i=1}^B L(x_i,y_i)\rightarrow \nabla L=\sum_{i=1}^B \nabla L(x_i,y_i)$$

Comment: Is there like $ \frac{1}{B} * \sum {L(x_i,y_i)}$  ?

Comment: The scalar multiplicand is not so important. Some definitions include it, some not. (it's not $B-1$)